# Looking for help wiring Peltier hear/cool in vehicle w/o the hvac console using dpdt relay

Tags: relay, peltier

I am trying to wire seats from a '12 Lincoln MKS into a '02 4runner.
Peltier & blower/fan were controlled via CAN Bus & HVAC module in Lincoln.

Not having that I am needing to devise a relay setup to power/control it.

Found a partial solution (youtube did not show full wiring) utilizing a 4 or 5 pin relay with a DPDT relay.

I have wiring diagram for oem heat/cool setup. (Not seeing an upload/attach option on phone)

Would anyone:

A) be able to assist with how I would need to wire spdt to dpdt to activate heat/cool with a pair of switches

B) be able to verify if above setup would allow for only on/off for both heat/cool

C) if answer to b is on/off only - how much harder would variable hot/cold be (say low/high for both)

D) verify if on/off switches could be replaced with potentiometers (but would want the variable current only to peltier, not fan/blower im guessing so not picturing wiring)

I can provide the stock (thru CAN) wiring diagram - also the utube link for the vid that shows 75% of the dpdt wiring what worked.

Was able to bypass the memory "box" for the power motors/switch but the Peltier wiring is past my Neophyte wiring abilities.

Thanks in advance.

Scott

Comment: Might be a better Q for the Motor Wehicles SE.